# Protractor typescript testing - salesforce webdriver iframe

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor, salesforce

Im trying to automate the creation of new application form in salesforce lightning,but getting the following issue while switching into the iframe

node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:182 return new Promise(function(done, reject) { ^ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Exception in PromiseRejectCallback: \node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:189 value.then(toWireValue).then(setValue, reject);

```
iframe:ElementFinder=element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'iframe- 
parent')]//iframe"));
async fillPersonalInformation() {
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.switchTo().frame(this.iframe);
await this.firstName.sendKeys("hii");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use `getWebElement()`.
Replace

```
browser.switchTo().frame(this.iframe);
```

by

```
browser.switchTo().frame(this.iframe.getWebElement());
```